# What is Atiyah's topological formulation of the odd order theorem?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, ho.history-overview

Here is a quote from an article by Daniel Gorenstein on the history of the classification of finite simple groups (available [here](http://www.ams.org/samplings/math-history/hmath1-gorenstein33.pdf)).

> During that year in Harvard, Thompson began his monumental classification of the minimal simple groups. He soon realized that he didn't need to know that *every* subgroup of the given subgroup was solvable, but only its local subgroups, and he dubbed such groups *N-groups*. However, the odd order theorem was still fresh in his mind. One afternoon I ran into him in Harvard Square and noticed he had a copy of Spanier's book on algebraic topology under his arm. "What in the world are you doing with Spanier?" I asked. **"Michael Atiyah has given a topological formulation of the solvability of groups of odd order and I want to see if it provides an alternate way of attacking the problem,"** was his reply.

What is this topological formulation of the solvability of groups of odd order?

Comment: I guess this would have been the time to ask: https://en-gb.facebook.com/events/783447311806240/

Comment: The Times just published this piece; it was also mentioned at the end of the Groups St. Andrews meeting. https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/mathematician-sir-michael-atiyah-88-hopes-to-prove-himself-again-with-new-solution-27b3jrhl7

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks! Since the article is behind a loginwall/paywall, I want to quote the most interesting part here: "The [Feit-Thompson] theorem runs to 255 pages of densely argued text. Sir Michael, without the use of a computer, has reduced it to 12 pages, simply explained. This week he sent it to 15 experts in the field and is waiting for their reaction."

Comment: The London Times article can be read here http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/atiyahtimes2017.pdf

Comment: Sounds like the paper should be submitted for publication if he's confident. Or better: the arXiv so more than 15 experts can look at it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In an email correspondence with Atiyah, I brought this up. The comments are meant to provide background for Thompson's remark.

*"When I first heard of FT I thought there should be a simpler proof using fixed point theorems and K-theory and I propagated the idea. The problem was that fixed point theorems could only deal with fixed points of elements or cyclic groups. So I knew we needed a theory that would cover fixed points of a whole group.  We could then apply it to the  action of a finite group on the projective space of the reduced regular representation."*

He went on further to say, *"It was only recently that I  realized we had to use equivariant K-theory and not its completion at the identity."* Then he mentioned his completion theorem of Brauer induction (with Segal), and how Snaith had given a topological proof of Brauer induction. Although not definitive, Atiyah may have a shortened proof of the Feit-Thompson theorem, and if so it would be presented in the near future.

In case it is helpful, I see that the quote from Gorenstein's paper was around 1960. Atiyah had published the finite group version of the Atiyah-Segal completion in 1961 (*"Characters and cohomology of finite groups"*). So, based on this recent email correspondence, these 1961 ideas make their appearance in a formulation of FT.

Comment: I've no clue whether this will be important, but I once corresponded with Snaith about how his proof of Brauer induction in his "Explicit...." book is not correct.

Comment: I only meant to provide explanation for the quote. I do not believe an actual proof will appear by Atiyah, but your comment would be relevant if it did.

Comment: Near future... or never, like the nonexistence of the complex structure on S6.

Comment: There is a recent preprint by Alain Connes which seems to have more information on Atiyah's ideas about the odd order theorem. Link: [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10761)

Comment: Quote from abstract: "In this note we investigate the idea of Michael Atiyah of using, as a possible approach to the Theorem of Feit-Thompson on the solvability of finite groups of odd order, the iterations of the transformation which replaces a representation of a finite group G on a finite dimensional complex vector space E by the difference between the associated representation of G on the sum of exterior powers of E and the trivial representation."